# Updating opencart to latest version admin working fine but frontend shows nothing

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

I successfully update my opencart site using instruction from here http://cartadvisor.com/blog/2013/05/01/how-to-upgrade-an-opencart-store-1-5/

admin Panel is working good, but front end shows nothing, only left sidebar with top nav bar with no css is showing with no links working

I am using opencart Version 1.5.6.1, console is showing no error

Please help me out

Comment: Please update your question with more information like opencart version, errors shown in pages, error logs etc.

Comment: I am using opencart Version 1.5.6.1, console is showing no error

Comment: To which version are you trying to convert? Also did you check whether the error log is on and is working fine?

Comment: I want to upgrade it on Version 2.1.0.1, everything is working fine,
I figure out problem is with my theme before uploading theme front end with default theme shows output but on uploading theme nothing is working on front end even default theme start showing nothing

Comment: Do you have: 'Display Errors' and 'Log Errors' set as 'Yes' in Opencart admin panel 'Settings' page? Is the theme compatible with opencart 2.1 ?

Comment: Yes Errors & log errors set as yes, I think theme is not compatible,
if I want to make it compatible is there anyway???

Comment: Contact the theme developer.